# how can I add an array into a single push data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push my data into array the following data: `["amruta", "amruta", "Badr Tharwat"]` into `author_name` , but however I got 3 arrays `["amruta"], ["amruta", "Badr Tharwat"], ["amruta", "amruta", "Badr Tharwat"]` how can I push them into a single one without the loop issue?

```
function populateTpl(tweets){
    var html = '<ul>';
    var matches = [];
    var author_name = [];
    for (var i = 0, lgth = tweets.length; i < lgth ; i++) {
      var tweetObject = tweets[i];
      author_name.push(tweetObject.author_data.name)
      console.log(author_name)
      console.log(tweetObject.tweetText)
      /*tweetObject.author.replace(/data-src-1x=("|')(.*?)("|')/g, function(a, b, match) {
        matches.push(match)
      });*/
    }
    //$('#example2').append(matches);
}
```

[tweetObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKeRA.png)

Comment: pls post  `tweetObject` content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 arrays because you have the console.log inside the for loop so it's executed each time. If you are only interested in the value of author_name when for loop has finished move it outside

```
function populateTpl(tweets){
    var html = '<ul>';
    var matches = [];
    var author_name = [];
    for (var i = 0, lgth = tweets.length; i < lgth ; i++) {
      var tweetObject = tweets[i];
      author_name.push(tweetObject.author_data.name)
    }
    console.log(author_name)
}
```